# io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: PodUploadWebSocketListener failed with no response

Tags: kubernetes, file-upload, openshift, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to upload a file in my Openshift Pod using the below Java Program and getting error:
Can anyone please help what may be wrong here. The location in new File(....) exists in my local and /usr/Tapan exists on my Pod which also has write permissions.

`

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    try (KubernetesClient client = new DefaultKubernetesClient()) {
        File fileToUpload = new File("C://Users/ntapan/Desktop/Tapan/Test.tar");
        client.pods().inNamespace("default")         // <- Namespace of Pod
        .withName("provision-mgmt-6bccb46c7b-lvgz7") // <- Name of Pod
        .file("/usr/Tapan")         // <- Target location of copied file inside Pod
        .upload(fileToUpload.toPath());      // <- Path of local file
        System.out.println("done");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`

io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: PodUploadWebSocketListener failed with no response
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.uploadable.PodUploadWebSocketListener.checkError(PodUploadWebSocketListener.java:91)
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.uploadable.PodUploadWebSocketListener.send(PodUploadWebSocketListener.java:114)
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.uploadable.PodUpload.copy(PodUpload.java:139)
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.uploadable.PodUpload.uploadFile(PodUpload.java:86)
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.uploadable.PodUpload.upload(PodUpload.java:64)
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.core.v1.PodOperationsImpl.lambda$upload$0(PodOperationsImpl.java:392)
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.OptionalDependencyWrapper.wrapRunWithOptionalDependency(OptionalDependencyWrapper.java:39)
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.core.v1.PodOperationsImpl.upload(PodOperationsImpl.java:390)
at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.internal.core.v1.PodOperationsImpl.upload(PodOperationsImpl.java:84)
at com.openshift.poc.UploadFileToPod.main(UploadFileToPod.java:16)

Comment: I spent some more time on this and discovered that since we are using Openshift Kubernetes environment which was hosted in my organization's Data Centre, so I had to be in VPN to get the upload functionality working correctly. So, I connected to VPN and the same code worked fine except I had to add one more line of code at the beginning. `client.getConfiguration().setUsername("<my SSO>");`